# LaTeX listings package: SQL comments defined by '--'

Tags: listings, sql

I am not able to both

1. Change the color of comments marked by --, AND
2. DO NOT replace hyphens (-) by the minus (−) sign.

A MRE follows.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=SQL, columns=fullflexible, showstringspaces=false,
  basicstyle=\small\sffamily, keywordstyle=\color{blue},%
  % alsodigit={-},
  alsoletter={-},
  % literate={-}{-}1, % Do not replace hyphen by minus symbol
  morecomment=[l][commentstyle]{--},%
  morecomment=[s][commentstyle]{/*}{*/},%
  commentstyle=\color{red},
  morekeywords={REFERENCES,OVER,PARTITION,LEAD}}

\begin{document}

A SQL query.

\begin{lstlisting}
CREATE TABLE Vehicle (
  VehicleId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  MakeId INTEGER NOT NULL,
  Model CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  CreationDate DATE NOT NULL,
  ...
  FOREIGN KEY (CustomerId) REFERENCES Makes(makeId),
  .. )
\end{lstlisting}

Another SQL query with comments. I cannot make to both
(1) Change the color of comments marked by \textsf{-{-}}, and
(2) DO NOT replace hyphens (\textsf{-}) by the minus ($-$) sign.

\begin{lstlisting}
SELECT getTime(tint '[1@2001-01-01, 2@2001-01-11, 1@2001-01-15)');
-- {[2001-01-01, 2001-01-15)}
SELECT getTime(tint '{[1@2001-01-01, 2@2001-01-11],[1@2001-01-15]}');
/* {[2001-01-01 00:00:00, 2001-01-11 00:00:00],
   [2001-01-15 00:00:00, 2001-01-15 00:00:00]} */
\end{lstlisting}

Another query with an underline `{\sffamily \_}' character.

\begin{lstlisting}
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Intersection(geometry 'Linestring(1 1,3 3)',
  geometry 'Linestring(1 3,3 1)'));
-- POINT(2 2)
\end{lstlisting}

\subsection*{Towards a Solution}

The last remaining problem after the suggestions here 
(in particular, using the cm-super fonts) is that when copy/pasting 
from the resulting PDF, the asterics are replaced by a square box.

\begin{lstlisting}[frame=single]
SELECT getTime(tint '{[1@2001-01-01, 2@2001-01-11],[1@2001-01-15]}');
/* {[2001-01-01 00:00:00, 2001-01-11 00:00:00],
   [2001-01-15 00:00:00, 2001-01-15 00:00:00]} */
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

### Rationale

With the space restrictions of today's publications, in particular 2-column ACM or IEEE conference proceedings, we simply cannot afford to use `\ttfamily` for showing SQL queries, only the starting `SELECT` consumes 1/4 of the column width. For this reason we would need to print SQL queries in a more compact font. Using `\sffamily` brings many problems that are not in the `\ttfamily`, in particular the replacement of hyphens with minus signs.

In the following figures the problem can be seen. The first figure is showing when commenting out `literate={-}{-}1`

[image: Red minus signs]

The second figure shows when the literate command above is activated.

[image: Black hyphens]

As another problem, when using the `\sffamily` and I copy/paste the text from the resulting PDF file, the underline characters are missing, which is problematic since students must be able to reproduce the SQL queries in their terminal.

This is the result of a copy/paste

SELECT ST AsText(ST Intersection(geometry ’Linestring(1 1,3 3)’, geometry ’Linestring(1 3,3 1)’));

In summary, we would need to write SQL queries with exactly the same behavior as in the `\ttfamily` but in a more compact font.

### Towards an Solution

The last remaining problem after the suggestions here (in particular, using the cm-super fonts) is that when copy/pasting from the resulting PDF, the asterics are replaced by a square box.

[image: Asterics replaced by square box]

Any idea to solve this ?

Comment: You should probably provide some images of what your current out put is. as it is not always obvious to see what you are refering to

Answer (score 4):

The issue with the hyphen is solved by applying the answer by Ulrike Fischer from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/424193. This is to add

```
\makeatletter
\lst@CCPutMacro
    \lst@ProcessOther {"2D}{\lst@ttfamily{-{}}{-}}
    \@empty\z@\@empty
\makeatother
```

Also `alsoletter={-},` is in comment.

The issue with the underscore is solved by applying the answer by egreg from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/42817. This is to add `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=SQL, columns=fullflexible, showstringspaces=false,
  basicstyle=\small\sffamily, keywordstyle=\color{blue},%
  % alsodigit={-},
%  alsoletter={-},
  % literate={-}{-}1, % Do not replace hyphen by minus symbol
  morecomment=[l][commentstyle]{--},%
  morecomment=[s][commentstyle]{/*}{*/},%
  commentstyle=\color{red},
  morekeywords={REFERENCES,OVER,PARTITION,LEAD}}
\makeatletter
\lst@CCPutMacro
    \lst@ProcessOther {"2D}{\lst@ttfamily{-{}}{-}}
    \@empty\z@\@empty
\makeatother

\begin{document}

A SQL query.

\begin{lstlisting}
CREATE TABLE Vehicle (
  VehicleId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  MakeId INTEGER NOT NULL,
  Model CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  CreationDate DATE NOT NULL,
  ...
  FOREIGN KEY (CustomerId) REFERENCES Makes(makeId),
  .. )
\end{lstlisting}

Another SQL query with comments. I cannot make to both
(1) Change the color of comments marked by \textsf{-{-}}, and
(2) DO NOT replace hyphens (\textsf{-}) by the minus ($-$) sign.

\begin{lstlisting}
SELECT getTime(tint '[1@2001-01-01, 2@2001-01-11, 1@2001-01-15)');
-- {[2001-01-01, 2001-01-15)}
SELECT getTime(tint '{[1@2001-01-01, 2@2001-01-11],[1@2001-01-15]}');
/* {[2001-01-01 00:00:00, 2001-01-11 00:00:00],
   [2001-01-15 00:00:00, 2001-01-15 00:00:00]} */
\end{lstlisting}

Another query with an underline `{\sffamily \_}' character.

\begin{lstlisting}
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Intersection(geometry 'Linestring(1 1,3 3)',
  geometry 'Linestring(1 3,3 1)'));
-- POINT(2 2)
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I knew the T1 trick but alas this produces raster fonts which some publishers DO NOT accept, they want vector fonts ....

Comment: @EstebanZimanyi Concerning the font: see the following questions: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56956/problem-with-siunitx-and-t1-fontenc, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1291/why-are-bitmap-fonts-used-automatically and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/548919/t1-fontenc-with-utf8-inputenc-dont-behave-well-together-in-the-output-pdf.

Comment: Alas, when using 
\usepackage{lmodern}
and copy/pasting from the PDF one query I obtain the following, which cannot be used by the students to reproduce the queries

SE L E C T
ST
A sT e x t ( ST
I n t e r se c t i o n ( g e o m
e t r y
’ L i n e st r i n g ( 1
1 , 3
3 ) ’ ,
g e o m
e t r y
’ L i n e st r i n g ( 1
3 , 3
1 ) ’ ) ) ;

Any idea how to solve this ?

Comment: @EstebanZimanyi I cannot reproduce the issue you describe. Both with and without `\usepackage{lmodern}` I can copy and paste the underscore correctly.

Comment: I am using MikTex on Windows. Would that be the problem ?

Comment: @EstebanZimanyi Did you try to use `cm-super` as suggested in the linked questions above? Does that solve the issue?

Comment: Little by little we are approaching a solution ! Many thanks for that ! There are at least 3 remaining problems when I copy/paste from the out pdf (1) the asterisc as in /* */ is replaced by a square box (2) An input of ~= get replaced by stacked ˜= (I cannot show it here in text format). (2) Despite that I use upquote=true the double quotes get replaced by closing double quotes ”. Any help on this ?

Comment: @EstebanZimanyi I cannot reproduce these issues as well. I would suggest to test if this behavior is dependent on `listings` and then asking a new question specifically focused on these issues and the used packages.

Comment: I updated the question above to show the problem. Many thanks for all your suggestions !

Answer (score 2):

#### Ad 2

To me your request ad 2 sounds like an artefact:

- the way a hyphen is rendered, depends on ...
- the font
- so you probably want `\ttfamily`, `courier` or the like

See e.g. this [question wrt listings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33039/using-ttfamily-with-bfseries-or-how-to-enable-bold-in-fixed-width-font).

Below I demonstrated this using

```
basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,% <<< rendering of - depends on font
```

but perhaps (!) read the manual about `basicstyle` again.

#### Ad 1

Ad 1, the coloration seems already to be in place ??

#### literate

For substitutions I also showed you some silly replacement of character sequences, should you need them:

```
  literate={get}{GOt**}1,%     <<< just for demonstration
```

However, you'll probably have a hard time ahead, should you insist on a certain rendering of hyphens in a specific font, which took a different route for a consistent font-layout.

#### Remarks

[As daleif stated](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/709278/latex-listings-package-sql-comments-defined-by#comment1764477_709278), I also would appreciate if you'd review and, where needed, put some more clarification and illustration into your question.

#### Result and code

[image: result]

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=SQL, columns=fullflexible, showstringspaces=false,
 % basicstyle=\small\sffamily,
  basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,% <<< rendering of - depends on font
  literate={get}{GOt**}1,%     <<< just for demonstration
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},%
  % alsodigit={-},
  alsoletter={-},
  % literate={-}{-}1, % Do not replace hyphen by minus symbol
  morecomment=[l][commentstyle]{--},%
  morecomment=[s][commentstyle]{/*}{*/},%
  commentstyle=\color{red},
  morekeywords={REFERENCES,OVER,PARTITION,LEAD}}

\begin{document}

A SQL query.

\begin{lstlisting}
CREATE TABLE Vehicle (
  VehicleId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  MakeId INTEGER NOT NULL,
  Model CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  CreationDate DATE NOT NULL,
  ...
  FOREIGN KEY (CustomerId) REFERENCES Makes(makeId),
  .. )
\end{lstlisting}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a different approach, taking into account that `literate` works like a replacement, which also takes regular expressions, see manual:

- it uses your original `basicstyle=\small\sffamily,`
- but replaces hyphes with a different font, like so:
- `literate={--}{\ttfamily{--}}1 {-}{\ttfamily{-}}1, % <<<<<`

Using regular expressions you could even more fine-tune font replacement, e.g. only for the ones in formatted dates etc.

[image: result]

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=SQL, columns=fullflexible, showstringspaces=false,
  basicstyle=\small\sffamily,
  literate={--}{\ttfamily{--}}1 {-}{\ttfamily{-}}1, % <<<<<
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},%
  % alsodigit={-},
  alsoletter={-},
  % literate={-}{-}1, % Do not replace hyphen by minus symbol
  morecomment=[l][commentstyle]{--},%
  morecomment=[s][commentstyle]{/*}{*/},%
  commentstyle=\color{red},
  morekeywords={REFERENCES,OVER,PARTITION,LEAD}}

\begin{document}

A SQL query.

\begin{lstlisting}
CREATE TABLE Vehicle (
  VehicleId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  MakeId INTEGER NOT NULL,
  Model CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  CreationDate DATE NOT NULL,
  ...
  FOREIGN KEY (CustomerId) REFERENCES Makes(makeId),
  .. )
\end{lstlisting}

Another SQL query with comments. I cannot make to both
(1) Change the color of comments marked by \textsf{-{-}}, and
(2) DO NOT replace hyphens (\textsf{-}) by the minus ($-$) sign.

\begin{lstlisting}
SELECT getTime(tint '[1@2001-01-01, 2@2001-01-11, 1@2001-01-15)');
-- {[2001-01-01, 2001-01-15)}
SELECT getTime(tint '{[1@2001-01-01, 2@2001-01-11],[1@2001-01-15]}');
/* {[2001-01-01 00:00:00, 2001-01-11 00:00:00],
   [2001-01-15 00:00:00, 2001-01-15 00:00:00]} */
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What about a full solution that solves ALL the problems :-) ?

Comment: As it often happens, a package can put constraints on what you still can do or no langer can. E.g. adding `\textcolor{}{}` within `literate` won't work. So if you want to stay with this package, my other solution may be a better approach https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/709535/245790 . // Else rewrite from scratch, which may not be too complicated, if you use scripting inside (e.g. latex3) or outside (e.g. PERL) of LaTeX to generate the required LaTeX code. At least this gives you the required flexibility listings might not have. // Finally, you could request the author.

Answer (score 0):

For information. Maybe you should take a look at `piton`. With that package, here is what you can do (your problems are directly solved). However, `piton` works only with LuaLaTeX.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{piton}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\PitonOptions{language=SQL}

\SetPitonStyle[SQL]
  {
    Keyword = \color{blue} ,
    Comment = \color{red} ,
    Name.Table = \color{black} ,
    Name.Field = \color{black} ,
    Name.Builtin = \color{black} ,
    String.Long = \color{black} ,
    Number = \color{black}
  }


\begin{document}

\setmonofont{lmsans10-regular.otf}

\begin{Piton}
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Intersection(geometry 'Linestring(1 1,3 3)',
  geometry 'Linestring(1 3,3 1)'));
-- POINT(2 2)
\end{Piton}

\begin{Piton}
SELECT getTime(tint '{[1@2001-01-01, 2@2001-01-11],[1@2001-01-15]}');
/* {[2001-01-01 00:00:00, 2001-01-11 00:00:00],
   [2001-01-15 00:00:00, 2001-01-15 00:00:00]} */
\end{Piton}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]